# Регулярное выражение для проверки email (с ограничением на почтовый домен)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем добрый день.

Помогите составить регулярное выражение проверки `email` следующим образом. Нужна проверка `email` адреса, но нужно что бы регулярное выражение не воспринимало почтовые сервисы `gmail, mail, yandex` и т.д., но пропускало остальные `email` адреса

Comment: [Прекратите проверять Email с помощью регулярных выражений!][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/175375/

Comment: С радостью бы отказался от регулярки но в моем случае она нужна.

Comment: сама регулярка будет простой. Но Вы не указали язык, на котором Вы собрались ее использовать. А от этого иногда многое зависит. 

В целом, если не привязываться к языку, то просто регуляркой вида `@gmail\.|@mail\.|@yandex\.|@t.d` выбирать нужные, а само условие в if инвертировать.

Comment: так уж точно не надо делать. Вместо одной регулярки будет две. Это надо в саму регулярку засунуть

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('~^.+\@(ya(ndex)?|(g(oogle)?)?mail|bk|list|inbox)\..+$~i', $email) 
{
    // запрещенный вариант почты
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если этот вопрос по PHP, то:

```
if(strpos($email, "@yandex.ru") and strpos($email, "@gmail.com") and strpos($email, "@mail.ru")) {
   echo 'Извините, но yandex, gmail и mail не поддерживаются';
}

else {
   // все отлично, печенки вкусные :) 
}
```

P.S. Ставьте метки лучше...

Comment: нет к сожалению решение через if и строковые функции для меня не подходит интересует только регулярное выражение и только одно такое возможно ??